Convert number to DaysOfWeek day names in SQL Server
I have a database table containing a DaysOfWeek int value that indicates which days of the week a job is going to run. The int value corresponds to the Win32 WeeklyTrigger.DaysOfWeek property for Windows Task scheduler found here.
For example, a value of 62 = Monday - Friday; a value of 127 = all 7 days.
What I am looking to do is replicate a function or process that I have seen in PowerShell with Enum flags in SQL Server where I can pass an INT value and return the day names.
Reference SO post: Convert Number to DayOfWeek List
Pseudo code for desired result:
CREATE TABLE #DaysOfWeek
(
    DayEnum int NOT NULL,
    DayName varchar(100) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO #DaysOfWeek
VALUES (1, 'Sunday'),
       (2, 'Monday'),
       (4, 'Tuesday'),
       (8, 'Wednesday'),
       (16, 'Thursday'),
       (32, 'Friday'),
       (64, 'Saturday')

SELECT DayName 
FROM #DaysOfWeek 
WHERE {IntValue} = 28

Result needs to be:
Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday

(4 + 8 + 16) = 28

You can use bitwise AND operator & to get the matching values from a bitmask, something like:
select *
from (
    VALUES
(1, 'Sunday'),
(2, 'Monday'),
(4, 'Tuesday'),
(8, 'Wednesday'),
(16, 'Thursday'),
(32, 'Friday'),
(64, 'Saturday')
) x (dayenum, dayname)
where 28 & x.dayenum > 0

Outputs:



dayenum
dayname




4
Tuesday


8
Wednesday


16
Thursday



